# NodeJS: Print out value of textrow nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have difficult problem when I try to print out a value from a textrow in node.js.

The code `console.log(data.res[0]);` prints out `[ TextRow { username: 'alex' } ]`

So to only print out **alex** in this case should be easy, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have tried printing it out by these different sorts of code.

```
console.log(data.res[0].username);

console.log(data.res.username);

console.log(data[0].res.username);
```

but these attemps either crashes the code, or prints out username as `undefined`.

How am I doing wrong in this?

Comment: If `data.res[0]` gives you `[ TextRow { username: 'alex' } ]` then that's an array. Most likely you need `data.res[0][0].username` to get the first item of the array and the `username` property from it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: `data.res[0][0].username`